# How to include master functions file in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have functions file.
In this file include many  functions
and i want to use them in my controllers
What am i do?
I use laravel 5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Calling Redirect::to() from within view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846035/laravel-calling-redirectto-from-within-view)

Comment: I think that you are mistake.

Comment: I have master functions file and i want include this file in my controllers and use that functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your function file is `additional_functions.php`, put it inside some folder like `app/my_functions`.

Then you need to add that file to autoload, you'll have to open *composer.json* and add such code:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
        "files": [
                   "app/my_functions/additional_functions.php"
       ]
    ...
}
```

After you're done, you only need to run `composer dump-autoload` to reload the autoload file.